# Auto-Index generation in C# .Net by coding

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, indexing

hello sir
In a Project of C# .net i have code to generate auto index, it it working fine. I have used logic as below;
1st count how many rows in table then retrieve what value has been stored in the table.
Then whatever the value it will be incremented by 1 for next field and hence it is next index.
There is problem occurs when index is more than 10. index in table is stored like this
1
10
11
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

so the last value in the table is 9 and next increment will produce 10, that is already
generated so it will be Primary key violation error.

So plz guide how to achieve auto index generation in my project.

Comment: Use an `AUTOINCREMENT` field in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you make the Column an [Identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo](
    [Foo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    //Other columns
)
```

or alter if database already created

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo](
    [Foo] [int] IDENTITY(<Enter your last maximum number in the database>,1) NOT NULL,
    //Other columns
)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of COUNTING ROWS, You need to get MAX value from table for that field/column, here as per given values it would be 11 and then increament it by +1.

So you need to use following query in your code,

```
    Select Max(Key Field) + 1 from [table name]//this will give you new key value i.e. 12
```

I suggest you to use Identity column, so you don't have to worry about increamenting primary key values.

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype of your autoindex... I have a doubt it is treated as a string. First thing you need to do is define the datatype to integer. So far your seeding is ok.